# A System.IO.FileNotFoundException is thrown anytime I try to read a file from my current directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, filenotfoundexception, system.io.file

I am trying to read a file in my current directory but anytime I run I get a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`. with the message `could not find file'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\cn.config`.

Below is my sample code....

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "cn.config");
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Current Directory will get the directory of the process running which in case of web app would **IIS.exe** or **IISExpress.exe**. You will need to get the path of executing assembly like :

```
string path = Path.Combine(
                        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
                          ), "cn.config");
```

or something like:

```
string path = Path.Combine(
              Path.GetDirectoryName(
              new System.Uri(
      System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath
                            )), "cn.config");
```